# Uknown PHP script taking 100% of the CPU

Tags: php, security, background-process

There is unknown PHP script running in the background of my system that I can't find and that re spawns every time I kill it.

A bit of information from ps about the process.

```
ps -Flww -p 280378
F S UID          PID    PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN    RSS PSR STIME TTY          TIME CMD
0 R root      280378    4725 99  80   0 -  6487 -      19328   2 15:47 ?        00:01:10 /usr/bin/php /var/www/bin/update-payments.php
```

`/var/www/bin/update-payments.php` does not exists, there is not even `/var/www/bin` directory there. I do not remember ever creating php file with that name.

How can I find origin of this process and stop it?

Comment: What is the output of `sudo readlink /proc/280378/exe`?  CMD can be faked.

Answer (score 1):

As PHP needs a web server to run, you can stop the web server to kill the PHP process. Before doing that, though, you might want to check running services to see if there's anything suspect:

```
systemctl list-units --all --type=service --no-pager
```

This will give you a list of 100+ services. See which ones are active and what they do. If you don't recognize a specific service, run it through a search engine to see what comes back.

If you can't find anything that looks suspicious, shut down the web server and take a look in your `/var/log/` and `/var/log/apache` directories to see if anything is complaining that the web server has gone away.

Stopping Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 stop
```

Stopping nginx:

```
sudo service nginx stop
```

Hope this helps you trace down the errant process.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer however I don't have enough reputation to post a comment yet.

Is your /usr/bin/php file the correct size?  Could it have been compromised and replaced with a defective/malicious one?

Have you tried to rename the /usr/bin/php file to something else to see if that process still gets launched?